Why not delete users who haven't come back for a certain amount of time?
I might be the only one who thinks this, but I find it rather annoying that there are a million derelict, unused profiles, especially unregistered ones, that ask (or occasionally answer) one, singular question, and then leave, never to return. It slightly irks me, and I don't know why. I've also seen users with a fair amount of rep (sometimes enough to get association bonus) and then on their profile "last seen 10 years ago" or something. There are people who leave (or, this is dark, but sometimes die), and I understand that, but if we know that there is a high likelihood those profiles will never be used again, why keep them? I will probably get criticized for this; I predict the most common rebuttal will be "Why not keep them, they're not hurting anything" or "It really doesn't matter, because XYZ reason" yadda yadda, et cetra, et cetra, but it honestly just feels like litter to me. I'm seeing these unused profiles on every site I'm on, including this one, and it annoys me because I have a hard time trusting these "one and done" users because they've not contributed enough for me to see if they're worth trusting. Take, for example, user Organic Marble, prominent on Space Exploration, been contributing for years and years and years, and has reliable sources for their information, accurate anectodical stories, and had experience in the field. This user has years of sample size to prove that they are trustworthy. On the other hand, you have this one and done guy who has nothing on their profile, one post of varying quality, and no evidence to suggest I should even trust this person, and apparently hasn't even seen their own post- or the site- since two-thousand-freaking-nine. By that point, it's pretty obvious that they're not coming back. We should delete that profile and, unless it might actually help someone, their post.
I am a controversial user. On SXSE, people are either indifferent to me, or straight up dislike me, and they aren't shy about saying (or implying) it, but I would say, despite that, the information I provide is pretty consistent and solid. I'm a curious person by nature and I want to learn, and I also love to teach others, but it's hard to teach a user that has been gone longer than I've even been here. I don't want to see these profiles that post once and then vanish into thin air. I know, I know, it doesn't hurt anyone to keep them around, but it doesn't feel right to me knowing that any comment I make won't ever be seen by the OP, especially if they provided no source and I don't know what their source was. I just wish that there was a system that tracks how long it's been from last logon (like we already have) and deletes any profile inactive for, let's say, 2 years. It wouldn't solve the problem, but it would clean up the "trash" of sorts.

https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/16/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

@M-- As it turns out, that post also says 2 years.

Some possible legal considerations: With respect to GDPR they might have to delete some personal data at some point. But on the other hand the comment license requires them to keep other data forever unless users themselves request dissociation.

@AustinOverton that's just one condition. In any case, I think that post already answers your question/addresses your proposal and its issues while putting forward a tangible alternative approach.

Interesting. So you say if I'm now taking e.g. two years leave, I'll become "trash"? I can see why you're frustrated, but the "off with their heads" won't solve this.

@ShadowWizard Poor word choice on my part.

And there goes all my rep...

You commented on the live meetup post about seeing this user’s reaction, but the comment is now deleted.


Take, for example, user Organic Marble, prominent on Space Exploration, been contributing for years and years and years, and has reliable sources for their information, accurate anectodical stories, and had experience in the field. This user has years of sample size to prove that they are trustworthy. On the other hand, you have this one and done guy who has nothing on their profile.

Let's continue that example: assume that Organic Marble finally lands on Mars, the wifi sucks there and they can't log into SE for a while. Then if SE deletes their profile, one won't be able to see their profile when assessing a post from them. Also, some one-and-done guys are knowledgeable too (example). Lastly, CC BY-SA requires attribution.

Personally, I believe that Organic Marble has all the skills to make an absolutely amazing Pringles cantenna that can pick up wifi from Earth...
